# Preserving Curve Geometries in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, well-known-text, svg, curved

Is there any way to represent a polygon geometry that contains a curve accurately in Leaflet (from WKT)? GeoJSON conversion from WKT is insufficient as it digitizes the points of a curve out to an approximation, it's necessary that curves be preserved as their mathematical representation (read:look circular/curved and not like a series of shortly connected lines at lower zoom levels).

I've checked out arc.js and leaflet-omnivore to start with, but my current thinking is that I would have to parse a WKT string into an SVG element and use either the D3 or RaphaelLayer plugins to properly render the layer while preserving curves. I also have performance concerns going the SVG route because I may have many polygons (hundreds to tens of thousands) to render in any given view.

I did find [this old question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44133/leaflet-how-to-draw-curved-lines) and have looked into the Leaflet.curve and Leaflet.Arc plugins but I don't think either of them could really apply to what I need (I'm also stuck with Leaflet 0.7x for maintainability reasons which eliminates a lot of plugins).

Anyone else have experience with this or a similar problem and have any suggestions or advice on balancing performance/accuracy of the curves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to represent a polygon geometry that contains a curve accurately in Leaflet (from WKT)?

No.

Leaflet currently does not handle curves (besides `L.Circle` and `L.CircleMarker`).

I suggest you have a deep look at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/vector/SVG.js and https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/vector/Polyline.js (among other source files). It should be possible to extend Leaflet's renderers to handle arcs, but that would need modifications across several classes.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to those, I'll take a look. If there is one thing I have plenty of experience with it's extending existing functionality.